# How to get input pdf_text to scale text in the same way that include svg does?

Tags: graphics, scaling

I would like to get `\scalebox{.5}{\input{file.pdf_latex}}` to scale text in the same way that `\includesvg[scale = .5]{file.svg}` does.

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/6273354697zrjfftwhjzgr) is the minimum working example.

For those who don't want to travel to the link, here is the code from the example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\includesvg[scale = .4]{SeriesCase4.svg}
    \caption{This is what it should be.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \scalebox{.4}{\input{SeriesCase4.pdf_tex}}
    \caption{The text scales down differently.}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use:

```
\include{calc}

\def\svgscale{.4}{\input{SeriesCase4.pdf_tex}}
```

This has also been added to the overleaf link.

This came from here: http://ctan.net/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.tex